# Creating an Outlook Backup Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin

Background: I'm working on an outlook addin and one of the things that I want it to do is to create backup copies of my outlook PST folders.

From the research I have done it appears that copying the files while in use isn't possible (please correct me if that's not right)... so having the addin copy the PST files isn't going to work. It would therefore seem that a second app (that executes after outlook has closed) would be necessary...

This is therefore what I'm envisaging:

App1 -- An outlook addin that allows me to specify the backup settings (which folders, how often, where to save the backups etc)

App2 -- Another app that can copy the PST folders after Outlook has closed

When Outlook closes, App1 will call App2 and 'tell' it what folders to copy and where to save them. 
My problem is I don't know how to get the two Apps to 'communicate' with each other...

NOTES:

- I don't need help with the functionality of either of the apps, I just need help on how to get them to work together
- Please don't suggest using any of the backup tools that are available - I want to build this into my outlook addin
- Please excuse the lack of correct terminology...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to have apps communicate: pipes, udp / tcp broadcasts, ...

I've found one of the simplest, for communicating between between apps on the same machine in the same session is to use .net's filewatch function.   Its rather easy you just program an app to watch for the creation of a file in a certain directory.   In your case App 2 would watch for a file App 1 created, when it sees it created, it reads it (App 1 would have written to it the settings it wants to pass over), and then after reading it App 2 deletes it.

More on Filewatcher here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: thanks for that (I'd never heard of this before). I'll have to experiment with it and see how it goes...